# c# first column in datagridview is getting incremented with negative values

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a datagridview connected to my sql database . it looks like this

```
create table Scule
(
    id int  Identity constraint pk_idscule Primary key, 
    unelte varchar(255),
    nume_persoana varchar (255),
    data_luat date,
    data_adus date
);
```

Whenever I add something in the datagridview my id is getting incremented but only visually with values starting from -1 going down..in the database it is getting saved well tho. i`m using windows forms c#. if i switch between the last two rows it will just increment it lower and lower for no reason. I've tried to remove the identity and constraint from id in sql but no result

Comment: What ORM are you using (meaning how are you getting the data into the datagridview)? My guess is that the ORM framework is adding a "temporary" negative ID to the records before they are saved. If that's the case, and you want the _actual_ ID, then you'd have to save the records before showing them in the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's how it works. I suspect you have a datatable as the backing for your grid, the primary key column is specified as being autoincrement with a negative step (the typical behavior when you create a DataSet and fill it with DataTables and TableAdapters)

It is important to remember that a DataSet is nothing at all to do with the database; it is a local set of containers in which data is held while you show it on a form and work with it. Adapters load it down from and save it up to a database

This auto negative number is a mechanism that allows you to have data in the local DataSet that satisfies the "a primary key as a number" constraint and also allows you to keep data together in a related way. So you've got a Scule- I'll pretend that's a School, where people learn stuff. A School has students so you'll probably have another table Students. Every Student has a SchoolId that associates them to a School. This means you can have a relationship between a school and Student

When you add a new School it gets an Id of -1. If you added 10 students they would have IDs between -1 down to -10, and their SchoolId would be -1

When you save the school to the db (and you need to save the school first so there is something the associate the students to) the DB will generate an actual school of, like 427

By magic (actually by running `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the insert that creates the school in the DB) the DataSet will download the real value of 427 and replace the -1 with it. If you have it configured to cascade this update (you should) then all the related students (those who have a school ID of -1 before the save) will also have their school if updated to 427. This way the data remains associated together:

- school ID is -1
- ten students have SchoolId -1
- school is saved and gets 427 in the dB
- school object in the DataSet gets 427
- student objects update to 427

The students can now all be saved to the db and they will be associated with the school 427

---

Mostly you should ignore this -1 value - you're only bothered about it because you can see it but generally we don't show the primary key to the user. You find the ID keeps decreasing when you go between the last row and the second to last because going into the last row makes a new temporary scule, but you then never fill it out so it's never committed. To prevent problems the temporary of is never reused so the negative increment keeps happening. Don't worry about it, it's absolutely unimportant in the grand scheme of things. The best thing you could do for yourself and your user sis remove the PK column from the grid so you can't see this happening